# MySQL KEY/UNIQUE KEY

Tags: mysql, sql, key

Google mostly answer the question about `PRIMARY KEY`/`UNIQUE KEY` difference. But what about `KEY`/`UNIQUE KEY` in MySQL? Does`t KEY in MySQL uniquely identify a tuple?

Answer (score 2):

No, `KEY` is alias for `INDEX`. `INDEX` doesn't have to be unique. If the `KEY`(INDEX) uniquely identified a tuple (a row) then it's a `UNIQUE KEY` (or a `PRIMARY KEY` depending on how you defined that key).

Answer (score 2):

Not at all - a column with a key can easily have duplicate values, the key helps with accessing them fast. A unique key will not allow to insert a row with an already existing value in that column.

Comment: "a column with a key can easily have duplicate values" -- surely this is the opposite of the generally accepted definition of a key?

Comment: not really! A key is not the same thing as a unique key - for the latter the generally accepted definition and MySQL's behaviour are to not accept duplicates

Comment: The context here is undoubtedly databases and in that context "key" is a contraction of "candidate key". Look in any generic (non-mySQL) book to discover this e.g. [this definition in first book I had to hand:](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TR8f5dtnC9IC&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=Then+K+is+a+candidate+key+(or+just+key+for+short)+for&source=bl&ots=jrP6trfE5S&sig=XuY1FsBNxGjbAPJmuFKMn3DXbEA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2bUGT97PBMeX8gOTvZnEAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Then%20K%20is%20a%20candidate%20key%20(or%20just%20key%20for%20short)%20for&f=false)

Comment: "I explained the basic idea of candidate keys in Chapter 1, but now I want to make the concept more precise. Here first is a definition:
Definition: Let K be a subset of the heading of relvar R. Then K is a candidate key (or just key for short) for R if and only if it possesses both of the following properties: Uniqueness: No possible value for R contains two distinct tuples with the same value for K. Irreducibility: No proper subset of K has the uniqueness property."

Comment: Do you have citations for *your* assertions?

Answer (score 0):

In database theory, 'key' is a synonym for a unique constraint. Some database management systems use an index (physical) to implement a unique constraint (logical) and is said to be a 'unique index'.

For the mySQL product, `KEY` is a synonym for a non-unique index and I think the usage is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Do you have any resource that says that `key` is a synonym for a unique constraint? I haven't read anywhere that `key` == unique constraint.

Comment: @N.B.: I think you would have an easier task searching for sources that 'key' does not imply uniqueness. Start with "superkey" then proceed to "candidate key" (a minimal superkey"), "primary key" (an arbitrary candidate key"), "foreign key" (references a candidate key) and beyond.

Comment: So bottom line is that you don't have the source confirming that key == unique key?

Comment: @N.B. sure I do: pop round to my place and I'll show you :) Or you could take those terms (superkey, candidate key, primary key, etc) and google them, look them up in your database book of choice, etc but avoid anything mySQL-specific, obviously.

Comment: ...find your first one [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=TR8f5dtnC9IC&pg=PT83&lpg=PT83&dq=Then+K+is+a+candidate+key+(or+just+key+for+short)+for&source=bl&ots=jrP6trfE5S&sig=XuY1FsBNxGjbAPJmuFKMn3DXbEA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2bUGT97PBMeX8gOTvZnEAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Then%20K%20is%20a%20candidate%20key%20(or%20just%20key%20for%20short)%20for&f=false) for free :)

Comment: Sorry, for a moment there I was under impression I could actually establish some sort of conversation with you but then I noticed that.. well, you have no clue what you're talking about. I won't downvote you, but I would carefully choose the words when explaining what's a key, index, unique constraint, constraint etc. Also, if you plan on looking down on products such as MySQL for no obvious reason, then we have nothing to talk about since I really don't like biased fanboys :) Have a nice day.

Comment: @N.B. "no clue"? I've provided one direct citation (via hyperlink) and lots of phrases for you to google. What kind of "source" were you expecting? I consider database products on their merits. I don't see how mySQL's abuse of the 'KEY` keyword is a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but @onedaywhen is correct here. In database theory, the term 'key' refers to candidate or super key and candidate key is a minimal super key. Primary key is chosen to be one of the candidate keys if several, hence 'key' IS unique. I can refer to my DB book used at university if necessary.

Comment: Yes, exactly! @onedaywhen